# concatenate (merge) two 2D vector (vector of vector) to a single 2D vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I m trying to concatenate (merge) two 2D vector (vector of vector) to a single 2D vector under some conditions. assume that I have 2 vector of vector v1 and v2. I want to create a new vector of vector v3 which consist of v1 and v2.

if v1's last element of each row contains an integer value of A & V2's first element of each row contains an integer value of B , they deserve to be merged as new a row of v3. or vice versa.

```
  v1    v2      v3
---A    B**   ---AB**
---B    A**   ---BA**
```

here is piece of C++ code that I wrote but unfortunately it is not working. Could you please check the code,what is problem .

```
vector <vector <> > v1;
vector <vector <> > v2;
vector<vector<int> >::iterator it1,it2;
int A,B;

for (it1 = v1.begin(); it1 != v1.end(); it1++)
{
    for (it2 = v2.begin(); it2 != v2.end(); it2++)
    {
        vector<int>::iterator it6,it7;
        it6=it1->end();
        it7=it2->begin();

        if (*it6 == A && *it7 == B)
        {
            vector<int> v3(it1->begin(),it1->end());
            v3.insert(v3.end(),it2->begin(),it2->end());    
        }
        else if (*it6 == B && *it7 == A)
        {
            vector<int> v3(it1->begin(),it1->end());
            v3.insert(v3.end(),it2->begin(),it2->end());               
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know whether it's the only bug, but you can't dereference an iterator that points to the `end()` of the vector.

Comment: yeah you were right that was the problem . thanx